# How to change Default Display Alert background Color in Styles.Xml for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to  change Default Display Alert background Color in Styles.Xml for Xamarin Forms?
Please Anyone help me?
I don't want Any plugins or etc.
I just need to Change default Display alert background Color

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that as of now, Changing the app theme to dark would change it.

Comment: If you don't want  to use any plugin, you could create a custom View and set the IsVisible when you want to display it .

Comment: @FreakyAli  thank you guys for your response,but Is there any other way to Acheive this?Please Help me

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT  thank you guys for your response,but Is there any other way to Acheive this?Please Help me

Comment: @Gowtham `styles.xml` seems like you are talking about Android, anyway, you've added the `xamarin.ios` tag. For a satisfying answer it'd be good to know what exactly you meant.

Comment: @PaulKertscher Thanks for your reply sir, But I am sure that this is not about android,I am asking for Xamarin Forms

Comment: @Gowtham There are still platform dependent parts in Xamarin.Forms and I am quite convinced that `style.xml` *is* platform specific. I am not quite sure whether you even *can*  change that in iOS.

Comment: @PaulKertscher Is there any way for Changing that only for  xamarin.android as of now?

Comment: It can be done by using Dependency service and way lot of code, but you can simply use a custom view as Lucas said. Why are you wanting to use the default Alert dialog? Any specific reason?

Comment: @Nikhileshwar I have tried this

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have tried what you have suggested(SEE BELOW CODE) but I want to background color in Default Display alert

Answer (score 0):

```
                    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Color="Black" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" ></ActivityIndicator>  
                    <Label x:Name="lblLoadingText" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Loading..."></Label>  
                </StackLayout>  
            </StackLayout>  
        </ContentView>
```

Comment: But I want to change that in Default one not using custom view