# How to change Background Color of Default Display alert in xamarin.android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to change default background color of display alert,I have tried many questions in different sites
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: didnt you already asked here? [How to change Default Display Alert background Color in Styles.Xml for Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628892/how-to-change-default-display-alert-background-color-in-styles-xml-for-xamarin-f)

Comment: Also, couln't you implement something like [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) to work like an Alert?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais I have already asked and tried the methods ,Then only I am asking again.Still I am not able to solve the issue

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais I have keep on asking this question for more than week ,but no one solved this issue.I have tried the following code

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais If someone give any new ideas only,i will be able to solve and thanks for the Negative reputation

Comment: 1º: whenever you are writing a new Question, SO gives you a list of similiar questions to AVOID duplicates, and it's our job as a comunity to mark as it, so people looking for anwsers to a problem, don't end up confused with so many similiar ones, 2º: People already gave you tools and solutions to your problem, have you tried to implement my sugestion atleast? 3º: SO is not a place where you ask a question, wait, and a solution to copy/paste into my code apears.4º: if you read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you will notice that it doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: I added an awnser with the sugestion i gave you. see if it fits your needs, also, try to be more polite around here and not "thanks for the negative reputation".

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais Sorry If i hurt you and I'll try to follow as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use `Rg.Plugins.Popup`, In the android, you can achieve it with a `AlertDialog` and custom style.You can call it by `DependencyService`.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeviceOpenAlertService))]
namespace App2.Droid
{
    class DeviceOpenAlertService : IDeviceOpenAlertService
    {
        public void Open()
        {

            var alert = new AlertDialog
                 .Builder(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, Resource.Style.MyDialogStyle)
                 .SetTitle("Alert Title")
                 .SetMessage("Do you want to close this application")
                 .SetPositiveButton("Yes", new myButtonClicklistener())
                 .SetNegativeButton("No", new myButtonClicklistener())
                 .Create();

            alert.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Add following style to the `styles.xml`

```
 <style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <!--Dialog Background Color-->
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#FF0000</item>

  </style>

  <style name="MyButtonsStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <!-- text color for the button -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
  </style>
```

Call it in the PCL.

```
 DependencyService.Get<IDeviceOpenAlertService>().Open();
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Leon Lu-MSFT but I have Implement this for IOS also because I am supposed to work in xamarin.forms(Android,IOS)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this behaviour using [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) to mimic the default display alert, this gives you more flexibility on how you want it to look.

First read the [Getting Started](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started), on Android you will need this in your OnCreate:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle); //Initialize the plugin

    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication (new App ());
}
```

After this, you need to create a View that extends from PopupPage:

Code Behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class AlertPage : PopupPage
{
    public AlertPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And here is how the Xaml shoul look like (i tried to mimic the default alert as much as possible, you can tweek it to achieve the look you want):

```
<popup:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="BlankAppTest.Views.AlertPage">

    <popup:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Bottom"
            PositionOut="Bottom"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True" />
    </popup:PopupPage.Animation>

    <StackLayout Margin="30,0,30,0" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#121212">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Alert Title" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="20,20,20,0"></Label>
            <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="3" TextColor="White" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="This is a Custom Popup made it Rg.Plugins.Popup to mimic the Default Android Alert" Margin="20,0"></Label>


            <Label Margin="0,0,0,20" Grid.Column="2" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="End" Text="Yes" TextColor="White"></Label>
            <Label Margin="0,0,0,20" Grid.Column="1" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="End" Text="No" TextColor="White"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</popup:PopupPage>
```

And this will act as a normal page, you can add Gesture Recognizers to the labels, bind the colors so the background color be dinamic, it's all up to you.

**The Default Alert:**

[image]

**The Final Result:**

[image]

Comment: Ricardo Dias Morais Thanks for the Rg.Plugin but I am not supposed to use Any Plugins

Comment: Ricardo Dias Morais Thanks but I have Implement this for IOS also because I am supposed to work in xamarin.forms(Android,IOS)

Comment: @Gowtham then remove the xamarin.android tag or add xamarin.ios, and you can also use this method for iOS, but i'm glad you manage to find a solution

Comment: Ok I will remove that .android tag and If you find any solution for IOS, please Comment here

Comment: @Gowtham you still want an RG.Plugin solution with iOS alert look? because Leon Lu anwser seems more what you are really looking for, i added this question as a diferent aproach from the native, since you could have more flexibility, also, both mine and his work for iOS, you just need a diferent implementation

Comment: Ok, I will check and confirm the solution for IOS